# For what values of $a > 0$ does $f(x,y)=(x^{2}+y^{a})^{-1} $ belong to $ L^{1}([0,1]^{2})?$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand for what values of $a>0$ the function
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2+y^a}$$
belongs to $L^1([0,1]^2)$.

I think $a \geq 2$ should work. But how to show that it is not the case for other values of $a$?

Comment: Why do you think $a \geq 2$ should work?

Comment: Why do you think $a=2$ should work?

Comment: The greater $a$ corresponds to greater $f$, so you should revise the direction of your search. Also, see advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Answer (score 1):

When we consider integrability, estimates within a constant factor are enough. Then the sum of two positive numbers is as good as their maximum, because
$$\max(a,b)\le a+b\le 2\max(a,b)$$
So, replace $x^2+y^a$ by $\max(x^2,y^a)$. Then we only need to integrate
$$
\iint \chi_{\{x^2<y^a\}}  y^{-a} \,dx\,dy + \iint \chi_{\{x^2>y^a\}}  x^{-2} \,dy\,dx
$$
The inner integral is easily found, since it's the integral of $1$ over an interval. The whole thing boils down to
$$
\int_0^1  y^{a/2}  y^{-a}  \,dy + \int_0^1  x^{2/a}  x^{-2} \,dx
$$
which I'm sure you can handle.